# Kong 0.10.3 KONG_RESPONSE_LATENCY header returns 0 and latency values don't match the documentation

Tags: api, latency, kong

I am using Kong 0.10.3 and it seems that the "latencies" object being logged by kong using the file logging plugin and the LATENCY headers in the response have erroneous values. 
Based on the Kong documentation, the "request" latency is overall latency, first byte in and last byte out, "proxy" is processing time of the upstream API and "Kong" latency is the time for Kong to execute plugins on the request/response. 
My issue is that the kong latency is frequently reported as 0 AND kong+proxy latency typically equals the request latency. Based on the documentation, I would think there would be a difference to account for transfer of the request/response payload.
I am trying to figure out if my API clients are slow, but these values returned seem to be faulty and not helping at all.
In this example, my request had a 6.6MB payload and Kong logged these latencies. 
if the proxy took 9648ms to do it's work, all I am left with is 38ms which is the Kong latency, and no remainder to account for the data transfer time.
                    "latencies": {
                        "request": 9686,
                        "proxy": 9648,
                        "kong": 38
                    }

Am I missing something or is this a Kong issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does the same issue exist in the latest [Kong Community Edition version 0.13](https://konghq.com/kong-community-edition/)?

Comment: We haven't upgraded yet, but I haven't seen any reports relating to this being a bug.